# Firebase, Digits Authentication Error, Activity Destroyed issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I am trying to login via Firebase and facing a weird issue. I can successfully login on all devices except some Samsung devices. While Debugging I found issue at:

```
package com.apponative.committeeapp.ui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.apponative.committeeapp.R;
import com.apponative.committeeapp.datamodles.User;
import com.apponative.committeeapp.firebase.FireBaseDbHandler;
import com.apponative.committeeapp.utils.CommitteeCallBack;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.GlideDrawableImageViewTarget;
import com.digits.sdk.android.AuthCallback;
import com.digits.sdk.android.AuthConfig;
import com.digits.sdk.android.Digits;
import com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsException;
import com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsSession;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity
        implements CommitteeCallBack.FireBaseAuthCallBack, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, AuthCallback {


    private int screenTag;
    private User user;
    private ImageView progressBar;

    // Firebase

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    AuthConfig.Builder builder = new AuthConfig.Builder();
    AuthConfig authConfig;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

        fireBaseDigitsAuth();
    }


    void fireBaseDigitsAuth() {

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                }
            }
        };

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        builder.withAuthCallBack(this);
        authConfig = builder.build();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            FireBaseDbHandler.getDbHandler(this).userProfileCheck(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().split("@")[0]);
        } else {
            Digits.authenticate(authConfig);
        }
    }

    public void signUpNewUser(final String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email + getString(R.string.firebase_domain), password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(SplashActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FireBaseDbHandler.getDbHandler(SplashActivity.this).userProfileCheck(email);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void signInExistingUser(final String email, final String password) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email + getString(R.string.firebase_domain), password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            signUpNewUser(email, password);
                        } else {
                            FireBaseDbHandler.getDbHandler(SplashActivity.this).userProfileCheck(email);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    void startMainActivity(int itemId, User user) {
//        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
//        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//        if (user != null) {
//            intent.putExtra("userId", user.getUserId());
//            intent.putExtra("userName", user.getUsername());
//        }
//        intent.putExtra("itemId", itemId);
//        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
      //  finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void SignInSuccess(User user) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.user = user;
        this.screenTag = R.string.tag_home;
         startMainActivity(screenTag, user);
    }

    @Override
    public void NewUserRegisteration() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.user = null;
        this.screenTag = R.string.tag_setprofile;
        startMainActivity(screenTag, user);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    @Override
    public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
        signInExistingUser(phoneNumber, phoneNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(DigitsException error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It throws error as below:

```
Process: com.apponative.committeeapp, PID: 28641
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1455)
                                                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
                                                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:667)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaay.zzt(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaw.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaw.zzs(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh.addOnCompleteListener(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.apponative.committeeapp.ui.SplashActivity.signInExistingUser(SplashActivity.java:115)
                                                                                 at com.apponative.committeeapp.ui.SplashActivity.success(SplashActivity.java:209)
                                                                                 at com.digits.sdk.android.WeakAuthCallback.success(WeakAuthCallback.java:32)
                                                                                 at com.digits.sdk.android.LoginResultReceiver.onReceiveResult(LoginResultReceiver.java:64)
                                                                                 at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver.send(ResultReceiver.java:59)
                                                                                 at android.os.ResultReceiver.send(ResultReceiver.java:93)
                                                                                 at com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsControllerImpl$1.run(DigitsControllerImpl.java:178)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I am not switching any fragment, it is a simple activity. I am confirming **mobile number via Twitter Digits sdk** prior to login. It works fine. I get crash only once right after confirmation via Digits. Relaunching app that does not send Digits confirmation runs smooth.

I wonder if Digits is doing some trouble with that. While debugging I have found that Twitter Digits `startPhoneNumberActivity`
with flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. What I assume these flags are destroying previous activity.

I have already tried following with this activity but no use:

```
android:persistent="true"
android:noHistory="false"
```

Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.---------"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post ur full activity

Comment: @AvinashRoy while debugging  I have found that Twitter Digits startPhoneNumber activity with flags 'Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP' . What I assume these flags are destroying previous activity.

Comment: add ur build.gradle file@SairaNawaz

Comment: sry build.gradle file

Comment: check the workaround it might help u out

Comment: or u can also put this in ur onCreate()- Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

Answer (score 0):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is the problem here which kills the activity.

calling the Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits()); in the onCreate() activity method can solve the problem for you.

Comment: I cannot remove it , as it is in Twiiter Digits ' class. Digits launch its activity through builder.

Comment: intent.set flags ,can't u remove it here??

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: it is SDK's class , Activity in that class is being started with a private method, and that class is 'locked' non- editable non exendable.

Comment: Nope, digits does not provide that access

Comment: it just takes parameter through a builder and launch activity via private method, that builder doesnot take any intent's parameters

Comment: but i can see it in ur code that u have commented that part

Comment: why don't u just skip the adding flags part and create a simple intent @SairaNawaz

Comment: I am not creating any intent, I am just starting Digits builder and that builder in its classes(sdk's classes etc) starting another activity. That activity is having flags etc. I can only set limited parameters through builder. You can view in this code, no where I have started any activity.

Comment: I do not say that falgs are creating issue, I said 'I assume' . Matter can be something else that I am unable to figure out.

Comment: matter is that ur splash activity is being killed and callbacks are unable to receive the data

Comment: Exactly, And I am no where Killing that. It is being killed by sdk I have no hold on.

Comment: just try this once and please let me know